# How to make SignalR hubs that require authorization honor loggin in / logging out?

Tags: asp.net-core, signalr, authorize-attribute, asp.net-core-signalr, asp.net-core-2.1

I have a simple chat implementation in SignalR. Everyone may read what others are typing, but only registered users may speak:

```cs
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Authorization;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.SignalR;
using System.Threading.Tasks;

namespace WebApplication1.Hubs
{
    public class ChatHub : Hub
    {
        [Authorize]
        public async Task SendMessage(string message)
        {
            await Clients.All.SendAsync("ReceiveMessage", Context.User.Identity.Name, message);
        }
    }
}
```

And it works. Except... When the user has the chat opened in one tab, but logs in / logs out in the other tab.

- When the user logs out in the other tab, they may still freely speak in the chat. The chat sends their messages with their nick they had before they logged out. This persists until the chat tab is reloaded.
- When the user is not logged in, but still opens chat in one tab, and then logs in in the other tab, they may still not speak in chat until they reload the chat tab.

Why, in spite of the presence of the `[Authorize]` attribute, does the `SendMessage` method still work even if the user is no longer authenticated?

How to fix this? How to make my chat hub follow authentications that happen after the client has connected?

ASP .NET Core 2.1 RC1, because 2.0 doesn't support SignalR.

EDIT: As per request from comments, `Startup.Configure`:

```cs
public void Configure(IApplicationBuilder app, IHostingEnvironment env)
{
    if (env.IsDevelopment())
    {
        app.UseDeveloperExceptionPage();
        app.UseDatabaseErrorPage();
    }
    else
    {
        app.UseExceptionHandler("/Error");
        app.UseHsts();
    }

    app.UseHttpsRedirection();
    app.UseStaticFiles();
    app.UseCookiePolicy();
    app.UseAuthentication();

    app.UseSignalR(routes =>
    {
        routes.MapHub<ChatHub>("/chathub");
    });

    app.UseMvc();
}
```

Comment: Show your `Startup.Configure` method.

Comment: @aaron See edited post.

Comment: Are you using cookies? If yes then that's the problem.

Comment: @davidfowl Am I using cookies? I thought Identity was supposed to use cookies. So how should I allow users to log in / out if not by cookies? Anyway, why does it matter? In my mental model, logging out should clean authentication-related cookies, so they should not be sent when client invokes hub methods, so the `Authorize` attribute should detect that these cookies are not sent and block the request. Is my mental model wrong?

Comment: @davidfowl To make it clear what is being used and what is not. I've reproduced this issue on an empty Razor pages project with enabled authentication. The only thing I did was to add a working, sample SignalR chat page as per [this learn.microsoft.com tutorial](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/signalr/get-started?view=aspnetcore-2.1&tabs=visual-studio). I've only deviated from this tutorial to include support for accounts: you can see above the resulting SignalR Hub.

Comment: In websocket credentials are only sent to establish the connexion and are not included in every frame. So once the connexion established there's no way for signalr to know that the user has logged off.

Comment: @J.Loscos, Make it an answer and I'll mark it accepted. So I guess I must make another socket channel that will send all tabs the information that the user has logged in/out and that they have to restart other connections?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In websocket credentials are only sent to establish the connexion and are not included in every frame. So once the connexion established there's no way for signalr to know that the user has logged off.

Like you said when the user logs off you could open another socket to send a message to all tabs that the user has logged off.

Or you could periodicaly check the cookies by javascript that to check the user is still log in and close the signalr connexion if he is not.

Another solution would be to use Shared Worker or Broadcast channel to send message between tabs.

Comment: Periodically checking cookies wouldn't work - the cookies available to the hub are the cookies when the websocket was first established